# AngularJS how to get data from <textarea> prefilled by Google Maps script

Tags: html, angularjs, google-maps, angular-promise, angularjs-service

I have a script that accesses the Goggle Maps API and fills in a `<textarea>` with results. How do I pass that prefilled data into an AngularJS controller?

```js
$scope.Add=function(msg){

$log.log(msg)
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="">
<div ng-controller="MapController">  

<div style="display:block">

    <div id="map" style="float:left"></div>

    <div style="float:left;">

  <textarea class="user" ng-model="user" id="points_textarea"></textarea>

    <input type="button" value="submit" ng-click="Add(user)" />

</div>


</div>
```

i am new to angularjs,

how to pass the data from textarea which is already prefilled from one of the javascript function in html, to the controller in angularjs

Any help please

Comment: You can use ng-model for that.

Comment: in textarea i have  prefilled data from one of the javascript function in html, i tried using ng-model, but data is passing to controller once i make little changes in it. not able to send as it is

Comment: Add you html and controller code

Comment: above is my html and js code.. "id" which i have used contains data which is filled in textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Bring the Google Maps functions into the AngularJS framework:

```
angular.module("gMap", [])
.service("gMap", function($q) {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;
  var origin = null;
  var destination = null;
  var waypoints = [];
  var markers = [];

  this.initialize = initialize;
  this.calcRoute = calcRoute;
  this.reset = reset;

  //functions here

});
```

### Modify the `calcRoute` function to return a promise:

```
function calcRoute() {        
    var mode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING;
    var request = {
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,
        waypoints: waypoints,
        travelMode: mode,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        avoidHighways: false
    };

    var pointsDefer = $q.defer();        
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        //Code snipped    
        ̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶p̶o̶i̶n̶t̶s̶_̶t̶e̶x̶t̶a̶r̶e̶a̶=̶d̶o̶c̶u̶m̶e̶n̶t̶.̶g̶e̶t̶E̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶B̶y̶I̶d̶(̶"̶p̶o̶i̶n̶t̶s̶_̶t̶e̶x̶t̶a̶r̶e̶a̶"̶)̶;̶
        ̶p̶o̶i̶n̶t̶s̶_̶t̶e̶x̶t̶a̶r̶e̶a̶.̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶ ̶=̶ ̶p̶o̶i̶n̶t̶s̶_̶t̶e̶x̶t̶;̶

        var pointsObj = {};
        pointsObj.routeCenter = response.routes[0].bounds.getCenter();
        pointsObj.routeSpan = response.routes[0].bounds.toSpan();
        pointsObj.routePoints = 
             response.routes[0].overview_path
             .map( _ => ({
               lat: _.lat(),
               lng: _.lng()
             }));

        pointsDefer.resolve(pointsObj);

        clearMarkers();
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else { pointsDefer.reject(status); };
    });        
    return pointsDefer.promise;
}
```

Notice that the above function removes the code that fills in the `<textarea>` with the data. Instead the code returns an AngularJS promise that resolves with the data.

## Replace the `<textarea>` in the HTML

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
    <h2>Google Map route point generator</h2>
    Click on the map to select the route points (up to 8).
    <br/><br/>
          <input type="button" value="Get Points" ng-click="vm.calcRoute()" />
    &nbsp;<input type="button" value="Reset" ng-click="vm.reset()" />
    <br/><br/>
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <br/>
         ̶<̶t̶e̶x̶t̶a̶r̶e̶a̶ ̶r̶e̶a̶d̶o̶n̶l̶y̶ ̶i̶d̶=̶"̶p̶o̶i̶n̶t̶s̶_̶t̶e̶x̶t̶a̶r̶e̶a̶"̶ ̶o̶n̶C̶l̶i̶c̶k̶=̶"̶s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶_̶a̶l̶l̶(̶)̶;̶"̶>̶
         ̶<̶/̶t̶e̶x̶t̶a̶r̶e̶a̶>̶ 
    <br/>
       {{vm.points | json}}
</body>
```

## The App

```
angular.module("app",['gMap'])
.run(function(gMap){
  gMap.initialize();
})
.controller("ctrl", function(gMap) {
  this.calcRoute = function() {
    var promise = gMap.calcRoute();
    promise.then( data => {
      this.points = data;
    })
  };
  this.reset = function() {
    gMap.reset();
    this.points = {};
  };
})
```

## The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/oMO2I2FmjkeTg2dxbPp1?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-model and ng-bind for these.
Check this in angular 4 - https://coursetro.com/posts/code/58/Angular-4-Property-Binding-Tutorial

And in Angular 1 - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<textarea rows="4">{{user.content}}</textarea>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('userCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
   'content': 'Theming support in an application can be pretty useful.'
   };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made you simple plnkr example
It will show prefilled data and on change of textarea it will show alert

Main thing to understand is ng-model, it is binding your input type="textarea" with variable textArea by using `ng-model="textArea"`

https://plnkr.co/edit/rml2JC8YZgLDTyLgq7x3?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can define your Textarea like this:

`<textarea ng-model='test_textarea'></textarea>`

Then you should initialize your textarea in controller like this:

```
$scope.test_textarea = "content";
```

Your angular app initializes when the documents DOM is ready - thus, overrides the value with your  $scope.test_textarea value.